# Sagemaker ImportError: Import by filename is not supported

Tags: tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

I have a custom algorithm for text prediction. I want to deploy that in sagemaker. I am following this tutorial.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/tf-example1.html

The only change from the tutorial is.

```
from sagemaker.tensorflow import TensorFlow

iris_estimator = TensorFlow(entry_point='/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/sagemaker.py',
                        role=role,
                        output_path=model_artifacts_location,
                        code_location=custom_code_upload_location,
                        train_instance_count=1,
                        train_instance_type='ml.c4.xlarge',
                        training_steps=1000,
                        evaluation_steps=100, source_dir="./", requirements_file="requirements.txt")
```

.

```
%%time
import boto3

train_data_location = 's3://sagemaker-<my bucket>'

iris_estimator.fit(train_data_location)
```

INFO: the dataset is at the root of the bucket.

error log

```
ValueError: Error training sagemaker-tensorflow-2018-06-19-07-11-13-634: Failed Reason: AlgorithmError: uncaught exception during training: Import by filename is not supported.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/container_support/training.py", line 36, in start
    fw.train()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf_container/train_entry_point.py", line 143, in train
    customer_script = env.import_user_module()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/container_support/environment.py", line 101, in import_user_module
    user_module = importlib.import_module(script)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue, The problem was using absolute path for `entry_point`. 

when you use a `source_dir` parameter the path to the `entry_point` should be relative to the `source_dir`

Answer (score 0):

I solved with:

```
region = boto3.Session().region_name
train_data_location = 's3://sagemaker-<my bucket>'.format(region)
```